# Pass ID from URL to Database is going null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My view looks like this
My url link http://localhost:63897/UploadImages?id=1361. 1361 is my `pr_id`.  I need to pass the id which is 1361 from url to database, but it is going null.

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult UploadImages(int id) {
    ViewBag.prid = id;
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImages([Bind(Include = "id,photo_url,photo_caption,photo_credit,pr_id")] Photo photos, HttpPostedFileBase photo_file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (photo_file != null && photo_file.FileName != null && photo_file.FileName != "")
        {
            try
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases"), Path.GetFileName(photo_file.FileName));
                photo_file.SaveAs(path);
                string f1 = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                string[] split = f1.Split('\\');
                string newpath = split[1];
                string imagepath = "~/Images/Releases/" + newpath;
                photos.photo_url = imagepath;
                _db.Photos.Add(photos);
                _db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

    }

    return View();

}
```

View :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pr_id, new { @Value = ViewBag.id })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view bag dictionary item's key is `prid`. But in your view code you are using a different key.

Use `ViewBag.prid`. Also use the `Hidden` helper method.

```
@Html.Hidden("pr_id", new { @value = ViewBag.prid })
```

Or just write plain HTML and set the `value` attribute value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="pr_id" value="@ViewBag.prid" />
```

Check the view source of the page to confirm the correct `value` attribute is set to the hidden input element with name `pr_id`

Assuming you fixed the wrong ViewBag key name, your existing approach will basically generate the below markup

```
<input Value="23" name="pr_id" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

Remember,  **`Value != value`**

**This is one major reason i do not use dynamic stuff like ViewBag.** You make a silly mistake like this and there are no warnings/errorrs from the IDE/compiler. It just silently fails :(  If you use a strongly typed view model, the compiler will complain when you make a silly typo.

Also do not use the `*For` method and try to manually overwrite the value/id/name etc. The helpers are designed to set the value/name/id attribute values properly. Consider using a view model and use these `For` methods with them. That will be less code.

If your view model has a property called `pr_id`, set that property value in your GET action, send that view model to the view and in the view(which is strongly typed to this view model), simply call `HiddenFor` method on that property

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.pr_id);
```

Comment: still its going null.

Comment: Use the hidden helper method. See the updated answer.